# Is FDM and TDM only used in circuit switched networks?

Tags: switching

I get the idea that TDM and FDM can be used in circuit switched networks, but what about packet switch ones? Can FDM be used?

Comment: Did the answer to your question help you? Please accept the answer in that case, so this question won't keep popping up.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Time-division multiplex and frequency-division multiplex are different schemes to multiplex a single physical line for different services or flow directions.

With packet-switched networks, the multiplex for different services is already integrated, so there's much less need for additional multiplexing. Wi-Fi uses (a kind of) FDM to allow multiple channels. These channels can be used independently or they may be bonded to increase the bandwidth of a single link. On copper, FDM and TDM aren't commonly used in LANs (due to baseband signaling) but xDSL and DOCSIS use FDM (they're not really packet-switched though). You could also argue that early Ethernet's CSMA/CD is a dynamic kind of TDM.

Wavelength-division multiplexing is in common use on optical fiber to extend their capacity. WDM is also used to multiplex a single fiber strand for bidirectional use (e.g. 1000BASE-BX and 10GBASE-BR).